# ES6: How to return promise from inside then block

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am hashing a password with a function that returns a promise. I am trying to use the result with `node-sqlite3`, which has a `db.run()` method that accepts a SQL command, an array of parameters, and an optional callback. I tried something like the following:

```
var maybeError = hashPassword("foo")
  .then(function(hashed) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
      db.run(
        "insert into blah hashed value ?",
        [hashed], 
        function(err) {
          if(err) reject(err); else resolve();
        }
      );
    });
  })
  .catch(//something else);
```

This idea works when not wrapped in the `.then()` block of the `hashPassword()` function. I want to export the `maybeError` Promise to a separate `server.js` file, which will use it to generate a HTTP status codes, etc.

### Edit:

The comments correctly identify an error in the orignal [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/n3cFWmhXtJq4QCz4lHSh?p=preview) that was an artifact of adapting the code to highlight the problem I was having.

Having corrected that error, I think there is still an error as shown in this [updated Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/qkf4GixVcfqJCRUZJx7l?p=preview).

```
// Simulate a database a la node-sqlite3
var fakeDb = function(sql, params, cb) {
  setTimeout(cb("Error"), 500);
};

// Test that the fakeDB() function works by itself
var noPromise = function(sql, params) {
  fakeDb(sql, params, function(e) {
    document.write(e);
  });
};

noPromise("foo", "bar");

// Wrap fakeDB() callback in single promise, that works
var singlePromise = function(sql, params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fakeDb(sql, params, function(e) {
      if (e) {
        reject(e);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
};

singlePromise("foo", "bar")
  .catch(function(e) {
    document.write(e);
  });


// Simulate a password hashing function that returns a promise
var hashPassword = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
  });
};

// Verify that the fake password hashing function works
hashPassword()
  .then(document.write("foo"));

/* Now attempt to return a promise from the fakeDB function,
 * but this time wrap that inside the then() block of hashPassword.
 * This doesn't work.
 */
var nestedPromise = hashPassword()
  .then(function(sql, params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      fakeDb(sql, params, function(e) {
        if (e) {
          reject(e);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  });

nestedPromise("foo", "bar") // <== This was the problem: should not have arguments.
  .catch(function(e) {
    document.write(e);
  })
  .then(function(x) {
    document.write(x);
  });
```

This writes `ErrorfooError` but not `ErrorfooErrorError` to the document. That `return` in the `nestedPromise()` function does not appear to be working.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "*This idea works when not wrapped in the .then() block*" - how does it not work in the form you've shown? What errors are you getting? Any logs?

Comment: See the Plunk I added. I think the attempted returned promise is null.

Comment: Why are you calling Promise as a function: `nestedPromise("foo", "bar")`? Promises don't work like that.

Comment: I updated the Plunk. I think that was an additional error.

Comment: I have updated the question to indicate that I fixed the error identified, but that I think I'm still having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error is not appearing from the call to `nestedPromise`.

That's because `nestedPromise` is a **Promise** (like `oldPromise`), not a function (unlike `noPromise` or `singlePromise`). You cannot call it. You can even see that in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: nestedPromise is not a function
```

Comment: You're right. But even having fixed that, I think my original problem remains: `return`ing a promise inside a `.then()` still seems not to work. See the revised question and revise Plunk. Thanks.

Comment: @Ethan: Your update did not fix the problem? the `hashPassword` function has nothing to do with that, it already works. See [this update](https://plnkr.co/edit/qoHhfzoyJYCdXMBMAZ2R?p=preview) that actually does the expected things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that I was calling `nestedPromise` with arguments. @Bergi edited my Plunk to remove the arguments. So it is possible to return a promise in the way I was attempting, as long as you don't screw up the function call like a moron.